# google-authenticator asks for verification code twice

Tags: ssh, multi-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I have implemented 2 factor authentication on a remote server using google-authenticator.  Login from the web console succeeds after password and single verification code queries.  But login from ssh asks for verification code 2 times.  Login is successful only if 2 successive totp codes are provided.
I have used `ssh -v <user@remotehost>` to verify that ssh publickey authentication is successful before the first query for verification code is made.

Config file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has the following settings:

```
# to restrict root login via ssh
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin no
# to enable login via 2FA
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

Config file `/etc/pam.d/sshd` has the following settings

```
# Standard Un*x authentication.
# @include common-auth

# for 2FA auth
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
auth required pam_permit.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Commenting out `auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok` in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` removes the duplicate challenge.

Running `google_authenticator` adds the pam module to `/etc/pam.d/common-session` making it unnecessary to add it to `ssh` also.